# Will upgrading to a new version of Bitcoin Core leave my wallet intact?

Tags: bitcoin-core, installation

If I download **Bitcoin Core 0.14.1** to my Windows 8 drive will it simply overwrite my existing **Bitcoin Core version v0.11.2 (64-bit)**, leaving all my BTC in my wallet intact?

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you mean "install" instead of download: Yes, it should not interfere with the `wallet.dat` at all, and the new version of Bitcoin Core will continue to work with it.

1. Regardless of your updating the software, you should have at least one backup of your `wallet.dat`. If you don't, create some now. Preferably before the software update. Be sure that Bitcoin Core is not running when you copy the `wallet.dat`.
2. Be sure to close Bitcoin Core before installing the new version.